# How do I detach the HuggingFace SageMaker training?

Tags: amazon-web-services, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, aws-batch

I am training a HuggingFace model remotely on [SageMaker integration](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/index). My training job takes more than two hours, and I would like to shut my computer off during training.

I use the following snippet to train the model:

```py
huggingface_estimator.fit(
  {
    'train': 's3://sagemaker-us-east-1-558105141721/samples/datasets/imdb/train',
    'test': 's3://sagemaker-us-east-1-558105141721/samples/datasets/imdb/test'
  }
)
```

How can I set up the trainer so that it the training process runs in the background so I can shut my computer down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set up the trainer so that it the training process runs in the background so I can shut my computer down?

You can!

Calling `fit` on a Hugging Face Estimator [starts](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/train#execute-training) the training job. Once a training job is started on SageMaker, it runs independently of your local machine.

You can shutdown your machine & the job will continue to run on SageMaker until it’s finished.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However, it's still a bit suboptimal for us, because there is no easy way to track the progress. If someone has some solutions to that, I would be interested to hear them.

Comment: @lmaooooo No worries. Feel free to ask a new question regarding tracking the progress :)

Comment: after I started the training job, how can I attach to the logs again? The docs linked only show how to download the finished model weights.